# Can you use a return statement to simply return a series of strings?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am new to Java / Spring-boot and Maven. Please excuse any ignorance.

I have been working on a program that uses a HTTP GET request to retrieve some JSON data. I use `String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())` to string the data. I then process the data to do with it what I want with it.

I am aware I cannot use `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())` again in this method. Is there a way to use my `return` statement to display selected pieces of my string data from within the application without using Thymeleaf or other JSP mapping methods. Format / aesthetic is not important at this stage; but if it can be done from within the return statement, that would help.

EDIT: added code

```
    public String get(String url, String acceptHeader, Optional<String> bearerToken) throws UnauthorizedException {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.addHeader("Accept", acceptHeader);
        if (bearerToken.isPresent()) {
            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken.get());
request.addHeader("Gov-Client-Connection-Method", "DESKTOP_APP_DIRECT");
request.addHeader("Gov-Client-Device-ID", deviceId);
request.addHeader("Gov-Client-User-IDs", userId);
request.addHeader("Gov-Client-Timezone", timeZone);
request.addHeader("Gov-Client-Screens", screens);
request.addHeader("Gov-Client-User-Agent", userAgent);
request.addHeader("Gov-Client-version", version);
        }

try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

//String HTTP GET request
String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

//Convert string "data" to JSONObject "root"
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(data);

//Array JSONObject "root" and cycle through elements
JSONArray obligations = root.getJSONArray("obligations");

for(int i = 0; i < obligations.length(); i++) {

//Create new JSONObject "jsonObligation" for each "root" iteration
JSONObject jsonObligation = obligations.getJSONObject(i);

//MAP individual nodes to OBLI.Class (specifically "periodKey")
OBLI Obligation = new OBLI();
String start = jsonObligation.getString("start");
String end = jsonObligation.getString("end");
String due = jsonObligation.getString("due");
String status = jsonObligation.getString("status");
String period = jsonObligation.getString("periodKey");
System.out.println(period);

//Create new ObjectMapper from file
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
File file = new File("file/location");

//Parse file to JsonNode "node" and output to system
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(file);
System.out.println(node);

//Cast JsonNode file to ObjectNode "object"
ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode) node;

//Find and update object."periodKey" with OBLI.Class String "period" and output to system
object.put("periodKey", period);
System.out.println(node);

//Write new "node" to file as String
try (FileWriter submit = new FileWriter("file/loction"))
{
submit.write(node.toString());
System.out.println("Updated file");
}    
}
//end of new code

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 401) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException();
            }
return "HOW CAN I DISPLAY SOME OF THE STRING DATA HERE?";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `response` is of what type? can you add some code you are fighting with?

Comment: Would be better if you can explain your requirement with an example and add sample code of what you've tried already.

Comment: @Deadpool, @ Madhu-Bhat Many thanks for your respones. I have added the code I have been working with.

Comment: This code does exactly what I want it to do; with the exception of allowing me to display some of the data in a return html page.

Comment: I am aware it is probably not elegant.

Comment: Still don't understand what you are trying to return.  What does "SOME OF THE STRING DATA" refer to?

Comment: `String start = jsonObligation.getString("start");
String end = jsonObligation.getString("end");
String due = jsonObligation.getString("due");
String status = jsonObligation.getString("status");` This data specifically, initially. And also potentiall, data from `file/location`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking how to return multiple strings at once from a method. That's one of the reasons classes and objects exist. Create a class with properties of type String, create an instance of that class and populate the various properties, and return that instance: `return new MyClass(start, end, due, status)`. Returning data to the caller and "displaying" data are two completely different things.

Comment: @JB Nizet, thanks for the response. So if I create a new class and define my standard setters and getters for start, end, due and status; the values would be returned using the code as shared?

Comment: Yes. All classes don't need setters and getters. If you just want to create an object and pass all the data using the constructor, you don't need setters. If what I explained is new to you, you really should stop using complex stuff like Spring Boot, and take sme serious time learning the basics of OOP.

Comment: @JB Nizet - or I could use OBLI.class, because they're already defined there?

Comment: If an OBLI is what you want to return, then sure, you can use that. Respecting the Java naming conventions, and using meaningful, understandable names, is also a must. Please, for your own good, take some time to read a book and practice with simple exercises with OOP.

Comment: @JB Nizet many thanks. I will do. I have been working with this technology for a very short period of time with a very tight deadline; I appreciate your candor and input.

Answer (score 1):

Like people have said in the comments, create an Object with multiple fields and with getters and setters and use that to return as many different strings as possible.

Also you may return a type ResponseEntity in Java instead of a String directly. It will automatically convert it to json for you.

for example do this

```
public ResponseEntity<?> get(String url, String acceptHeader, Optional<String> bearerToken) throws UnauthorizedException {
    //...
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 401) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        YourOwnResponseObject obj = new YourOwnResponseObject();
        obj.setFirstString("first String");
        obj.setSecondString("second String");
        ///...
        return new ResponseEntity(obj, HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```